# Dependency injection, but not into a controller

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I recently began experimenting with DI. I am using Unity Ioc to inject an EmailService from by Business Logic Layer into EmailServiceWrapper in the presentation layer which is then instantiated, my code is as follows:

```
public class EmailServiceWrapper : IIdentityMessageService
{
    private readonly IEmailService _emailService;
    public EmailServiceWrapper(IEmailService emailService)
    {
        this._emailService = emailService;
    }
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        await _emailService.configSendGridasync(message.Body, message.Subject, new MailAddress(message.Destination));
    }
}
```

I register the mapping like so:

```
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<IEmailService, EmailServiceGmail>();
    }
```

Finally in my ApplicationUserManager.cs I try to do the following:

```
    appUserManager.EmailService = new EmailServiceWrapper(); //Dependency injection?
```

**I get an error: "EmailServiceWrapper" does not have a constructor that takes 0 arguments.** I am aware of what this means, but I am not sure how to set this up, I've seen many examples online about injecting dependencies into controllers but what about this case? Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aim of Unity is that you don't explicitly construct objects yourself, with all the inner constructors that would require; instead you get the container to do it for you:

```
appUserManager.EmailService = container.Resolve<EmailServiceWrapper>();
```

The point of

```
container.RegisterType<IEmailService, EmailServiceGmail>();
```

is to give the container the information it needs to new up any object that requires an IEmailService.